# TypeScript type signatures for functions with variable argument counts

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble defining interfaces with function members that accept variable amounts of arguments. Take the following object literal as an example:

```
var obj = {
    func: () => {
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            console.log(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

I'd like to be able to define an interface such as:

```
interface IExample {
    func: ( ??? ) => void;
}
```

So that the following code can compile without error:

```
var test = (o: IExample) {
    o.func("a");
    o.func("a", "b");
    o.func("a", "b", "c");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 304, accepted):

TypeScript uses the ECMAScript 6 spread proposal,

> http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:spread

but adds type annotations so this would look like,

```
interface Example {
    func(...args: any[]): void;
}
```

Comment: Perfect -- for some reason I was not able to find anything about this in the language spec document, but it seems to work just fine. Thank you.

Comment: @nxn Page 50/51 in the specs : RestParameter

Comment: @PulsarBlow Ah, I wasn't familiar with them being called Rest Parameters. Thank you for letting me know where to find them in the spec.

Comment: how can I omit the type? I get `sqliteiface.ts(51,10): ... parameter must have array type`

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I realize that I'm very late but for anyone who stumbles upon this post, make sure you don't forget to mark the RestParameter as an array. `...args:any[]` is correct but `...args:any` is not.

Comment: what is "func" doing in the front of (...args: any[]), from what I can tell it is superfluous?

Comment: @AlexanderMills func is the name of the function.

Comment: As a side note, the interface name should be `Example`. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#names

Comment: Changed the example to match standard naming conventions

Comment: I think the syntax should be 
    func: (...args: any[]) => void;
As the example here did not compile for me

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChkzkYBXEBACgDpG4oBzAZwC5k4QBPAbQC6ASi4A3APbAAJgG5iAXyA

The above syntax is correct as of 4.0.2

Comment: why is `...args: any` incorrect? It seems more convenient to me. `any[]` looks like if every parameter would be an array of some type.

Comment: This was a stylistic choice by the TypeScript designers. 

The type of `args` is an array not `any` so it is a bit more clear in that way but other language designers, such as Kotlin's, agree with you that the `: any` looks like the type of the expected parameters and Kotlin's syntax matches your expectations.

Comment: Perhaps since `unknown` has been added to the language (TS 3.0 in 2018), it's the right choice here (as it provides some type safety)?

Comment: Yes, `unknown` is a better choice here but I will keep the example using `any` as the argument type is not that important to the answer and using a newer feature might be more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to chuck's answer, you don't need to have an interface defined as such. You can just do the `...` directly in the method:

```
class Header { constructor(public name: string, public value: string) {} }

getHeaders(...additionalHeaders: Header[]): HttpHeaders {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    if (additionalHeaders && additionalHeaders.length)
        for (var header of additionalHeaders)
            headers.append(header.name, header.value);

    return headers;
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
headers: this.getHeaders(new Header('X-Auth-Token', this.getToken()))
```

Or

```
headers: this.getHeaders(new Header('X-Auth-Token', this.getToken()), new Header('Something', "Else"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ...args[] argument is not used Typescript still creates an array in the Javascript and copies the arguments to it.

To avoid this unnecessariness you can make a prototype for the function as well as the function, thus:-

```
function format_n(str: string, ... $n: any[]): string;
function format_n(str: string): string {
    return str.replace(/%(\d+)/g, (_, n) => format_n.arguments[n]);
}
```