# *args like behavior in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a function callRest.

```
public callRest(payload: any, url: string){
    this.$httpservice.post(url, payload);
}
```

I want to be able to pass multiple arguments in payload. For example, payload could have two variables: data & headers or just one: data. In both cases I would like post request to send all the arguments sent inside payload. Something like

```
this.$httpservice.post(url, data, header); & 
this.$httpservice.post(url, data);//depending upon the structure of payload. 
//payload can be anything we want to define it as.
```

I could've done this in Python with something like *payload. How do I achieve this behavior in Typescript? My problem is two folds, how I do pass variable arguments and then how do I pass these variables arguments to the `post` which is called inside `callRest`.

PS: payload could have many such variables. I would prefer to not restrict it to data & header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739149/typescript-type-signatures-for-functions-with-variable-argument-counts

Comment: You can use `arguments` inside your function `callRest`.

Comment: refer:- http://codeinreview.com/73/default-arguments-and-variable-arguments-in-typescript/

Comment: @hansmaad how do I pass the arguments passed as ...params: any[] to my post function? Right now I am writing ``.post(url, params)`` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use destructuring to declare the parameter and the spread operator when passing the call through:

```
function callRest(url: string, ...payload: any[]) {
    this.$httpservice.post(url, ...payload);
}
```

Note that you'll want to make the payload the last argument instead of the first as you had it originally.

Comment: I get the following error message: error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: What is the signature of `$httpservice.post()` ?

Comment: use url and data as required parameter and config as optional parameter. It will surely work... see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L1321 for more info

Comment: I guess the problem is that post expects data:any rather than data:any[]. See this: `(method) angular.IHttpService.post<T>(url: string, data: any, config?: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig):`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take payload as an optional parameter which should have a type any[].

e.g.

```
function callRest(url: string, ...payload: any[]) {
    if ( payload.length == 1) {
        this.$httpservice.post(url, payload[0]);
    } else if (payload.length == 2) {
        this.$httpservice.post(url, payload[0], payload[1]);
    } 
}
```

If statement can be increased according to the need.

2nd method:-

```
function callRest(url: string, data: string, payload?: angular.IRequestShortcutConfig ) {
    this.$httpService.post(url, data, payload);
}
```

See if it helps.

For more info Refer [Variable arguments in typescript](http://codeinreview.com/73/default-arguments-and-variable-arguments-in-typescript/)

Regards

Ajay

Comment: I would like to avoid writing conditional statements on payload.length like you have. I do not do anything different in any of the if statements. I just call post with all of the arguments that are part of payload.

Also, what should payload look like?