# How to generically forward function signature with type safety in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if there is a general solution to forward function arguments in TypeScript fully type-safe. Consider you are given an arbitrary function `f`. The question is, how to declare a function that has exactly the same type signature as `f`.

This problem arises for instance when wrapping a function:

```
function wrappedFunc(func: (...args: any[]) => any) {
  return (...args: any[]) => {
    console.log("func has been called");
    return func(...args);
  };
}

let f = wrappedFunc((a: number, b: number) => a + b);
```

Basically using `...args: any[]` works, i.e., `f(1, 2)` would return `3` as expected. However `f` has lost the type signature of `(a: number, b: number) => number`, and instead accept any inputs and has a return type of `any`.

Is there a way to write `wrappedFunc` so that the function it returns perfectly forwards the signature of its `func` argument?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12739149/1804173) which explains the `...args: any[]` trick, but doesn't cover type-safe forwarding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) that uses the [`Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) helpers. The correct types will then be inferred based on what you pass in:

```
function wrappedFunc<T extends ((...args: any[]) => any)>(func: T) {
  return (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
    console.log("func has been called");
    return func(...args);
  };
}

// `f` becomes `(a: number, b: number) => number`
let f = wrappedFunc((a: number, b: number) => a + b);
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for and well explained, thanks!

Comment: The outer parenthesis pair of the `extends` seems dedundant i.e.  `wrappedFunc<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>` works too.

Answer (score 1):

@Etheryte's answer works perfectly when the function being forwarded does not change over time. I upvoted it indeed. But if the original `wrappedFunc` changes over time, the code above will not work because it will run the old code that existed at the moment the `f` function was instantiated.

That happens when you import a function from another module that you don't know how the code inside works. For example, in TypeORM when we import a model instance to execute the `newInstance` function, the wrapping will not always work because TypeORM will change the implementation of the `newInstance` function along the loading process. The `newInstance` argument parameters types will be preserved though.

So, a more guaranteed way to forward a function, but not as generic as @Etheryte's, is this one bellow. It will get the last fresh version of the wrapped function in execution time, not in instantiation time:

```js
let f = (...args: Parameters<typeof wrappedFunc>) => {
  return wrappedFunc(...args);
}
```